# A time-series where the average of the difference depends only on the interval

Tags: time-series, differences

Consider a time-series: $\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_T\}$.

Then, we can think of the difference like $X_{t+r}-X_{t}$, where $r$ is an integer.

Here, I am wondering whether there is any time-series process that satisfies a property that the average of $X_{t+r}-X_t$ (i.e. $E[X_{t+r}-X_t]$) depends only on the interval $r$.

I am checking if some famous processes such as AR(1) are those kinds of processes.

But, I am not sure about the answer yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the following analysis we repeatedly exploit linearity of expectation to characterize such processes.

---

Let $\beta(r) = E[X_{t+r}-X_{t}].$  Replacing $X_t$ by $X_t - X_0$ (it is convenient to start indexing times with $t=0$), we may assume $X_0=0$ and because $\beta(r)$ depends only on $r,$

$$\beta(r) = E[X_r].$$

Notice that since

$$\beta(r+1) = E[X_{t+r+1}-X_t] = E[X_{t+r+1} - X_{t+r}] + E[X_{t+r} - X_t] = \beta(1) + \beta(r),$$

then by induction on the natural number $r,$

$$\beta(r) = r\beta(1).$$

Consequently, we are motivated to analyze the derived time series

$$Y_t = X_t - X_0 - r\beta(1),$$

which by construction is *first-order stationary with constant zero mean.*

Conversely, let $Y_t$ be any zero-mean first-order stationary process, let $\mu$ and $\beta(1)$ be any numbers, and set

$$X_t = \mu + t\beta(1) + Y_t.$$

Then

$$E[X_{t+r} - X_t] = E[(\mu + (t+r)\beta(1) + Y_{t+r}) - (\mu + (t)\beta(1) + Y_{t})] = r\beta(1)$$

depends only on $r.$

> All such time-series processes $X_t,$ for which the expected differences depend only on the lag $r,$ are the sum of a linear function of the natural numbers $t\to E[X_0] + t\beta(1)$ and a first-order stationary time series process $Y_t.$

Comment: It is a perfect answer thank you so much.